# Coupling when achieve a component pattern in a c++ render

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, components, game-engine

Now,I hava a class with some components to do things while these components also need the reference of this parent class to update states.They coupling with each other make the design hard.Here is a example code snippet:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
class man {
public:
    int health{ 10 }, x, y;
    void update();
private:
    class moveCom *_move;
    class judgeCom *_judge;
};
class moveCom {
public:
    void update(man&m) {
        ++m.x;
        ++m.y;
    }
};
class judgeCom {
public:
    void update(man&m) {
        if(rand()%10 <= 5)
            ++m.health;
        else --m.health;
    }
};
void man::update() {
    _move->update(*this);
    _judge->update(*this);
    cout << health << " " << x << " " << y << endl;
}
int main() {
    man m;
    while (1) {
        Sleep(200);
        m.update();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code can  only work in the same cpp file which means if split them into different hpp/cpp will cause compile error.Is there any practice to do better?

Edit:Sorry,i try it again and it okay with separate.

Comment: separate to file should make no difference.

Comment: Your `judgeCom`s could accept the current health only as parameter, calculate the new value based on and return it. x and y could be packed into a struct `Coordinates` which could then be passed as reference to be modified by moveCom. This way, the two `Com`s wouldn't have to be aware of `Man`.

Comment: The still naive but better way would be to create a base `Component` `class` ( with a virtual destructor and update function ) and store a list of unique ptr s to it in `man` then have every Component derive your Component class, then when creating a new component add a pointer to its base to your component lis. Then you can iterate the list and call update on all the components you want without having to manually add entries. There's other things you could redesign to aswell, data oriented design and specifically entity component systems having been gaining traction in the game dev community.